# Any way to make the code more simple?

Tags: jquery

I have made jQuery code which is addclass when click and remove others.

```
$('.list_qna li a').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.list_box li a').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.list_contact li a').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault();
});




<ul class="list_qna">
    <li>
        <a href="#">list</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">list</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list_box ">
    <li>
        <a href="#">list</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">list</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list_contact ">
    <li>
        <a href="#">list</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">list</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to make the code more simple for different elements?
Please help.

*updated with HTML structure

Comment: Can you also post the structure of HTML, it is not clear what you are trying to get, what the goal is.

Comment: @skobaljic  updated with HTML structure

Comment: Basic mode: `$('.list_qna li a,.list_box li a,.list_contact li a')...` slightly improved: `$('.list_qna,.list_box,.list_contact').find('li a')...` better would be to give all your `ul`s the same class (maybe a new one) or use the parent `div` if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want same behavior for all lists, than it is best to use same class on all of them. Here is an example:

```js
$('.list_selection li a').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.list_selection {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.list_selection li {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.list_selection a {
    display: block;
    background: none red;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
.list_selection .selected a {
    background: none yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list_qna list_selection">
    <li>List qna 1<a>select</a></li>
    <li>List qna 2<a>select</a></li>
    <li>List qna 3<a>select</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list_box list_selection">
    <li>List box 1<a>select</a></li>
    <li>List box 2<a>select</a></li>
    <li>List box 3<a>select</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list_contact list_selection">
    <li>List contact 1<a>select</a></li>
    <li>List contact 2<a>select</a></li>
    <li>List contact 3<a>select</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t51jykhm/1/).

I case you cannot or do not want to add the class, than you can use [jQuery Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) (read: comma separated selectors) this way:

```
$('.list_qna li a, .list_box li a, .list_contact li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
});
```

> Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.